# Sorting a grouped list of Servers by load and distance

Tags: linq

I am trying to write a linq query to sort a list of Server objects.
The key properties of the Server are Load (percentage 0.1 etc.) and DistanceInKm.

```
e.g server is var server = new Server{Load=0.1,DistanceInKm=200}
```

A server can have a nullable load. In this case when grouping I want to push nullable loads to the back of its group.

So for first case:
Server list ( loc means same location/distance s1 means server 1,2..)
Loc1= 3km, Loc2=1km, Lo3=2km

> 1. LOC1 S1 : Load NULL
> 2. LOC1 S2 : Load 0.1
> 3. LOC2 S1 : Load 0.7
> 4. LOC2 S2 : Load 0.1
> 5. LOC3 S1 : Load 0.1

Result:

> 1. LOC2 S2 : Load 0.1
> 2. LOC3 S1 : Load 0.1
> 3. LOC1 S2 : Load 0.1
> 4. LOC2 S1 : Load 0.7
> 5. LOC1 S1 : Load NULL

The above logic produced the Result. The aim is to have a list of servers ordered by distance first for each ordered load..
 However for the following list:

> 1. LOC1 S1 : Load NULL
> 2. LOC1 S2 : Load 0.1
> 3. LOC1 S3 : Load 0.6
> 4. LOC1 S4 : Load 0.2
> 5. LOC2 S1 : Load 0.7
> 6. LOC2 S2 : Load 0.1
> 7. LOC2 S3 : Load 0.2
> 8. LOC3 S1 : Load 0.1

But the result gives:

> 1. LOC2 S2 : Load 0.1
>
>    2. LOC3 S1 : Load 0.1
>    3. LOC1 S2 : Load 0.1
>    4. LOC2 S3 : Load 0.2
>    5. LOC1 S4 : Load 0.2
>    6. LOC1 S3 : Load 0.6 --> **this is incorrect. Because it should be loc2 s1 Load 0.7 because it is nearer by distance**

Maybe i did not explain the problem correctly. I kind of figured it out in pseudo code to be something like this:

While (repeat is true)
For each group
  take the first item (use skip(count) and take(1)
increment count

Repeat for each group but then take the n+1 item. Repeat until 
there are no longer any items to iterate in all groups. This should yield
the items from the groups in order. Since the groups were grouped by distance in order and the items themselves in load order by traversing each group first, second.. and so forth should produce an ordered flat list by distance and load

Comment: It seems to me that the first ordering (in `groupedByDistance`) does exactly what you want. The second query overwrites this ordering.

Comment: the first ordering for the group by does not order by load that is why i apply separate ordering on the flat list.

Comment: *does not order by load* ? `ThenBy(x => x.LoadPercentage)`